# the message appears when the variable is changed

Tags: android, firebase

hello I want the message to appear only when you change comment

```
    public class activity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChildEventListener {


        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
        DatabaseReference myRef;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_showcomments);


            CallFirebase();

    }


    public void CallFirebase()
        {
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
            myRef = myRef.child(id);
            myRef.addChildEventListener(showcomments.this);
        }


@Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
```

this works when you change any variable inside id , but I just want to change comment

I tried to change this but it does not work

```
public void CallFirebase()
    {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        myRef = myRef.child(id).child("comment");
        myRef.addChildEventListener(showcomments.this);
    }
```

what is the problem here I hope to get a good answer

Comment: Your message also appears onChildAdded ?

Comment: yes please help me

Comment: any answer please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you are initializing `myRef` and after that you are assigning a new reference to the same `myRef` variable. To solve the problem, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference commentRef = rootRef.child(id).child("comment");
commentRef.addChildEventListener(/* ... */)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: does not work when added by this , 

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference commentRef = rootRef.child(id).child("comment");
        commentRef.addChildEventListener(this);

Comment: but when removing this works successfully please help me , child("comment");

Comment: there is no error I just want when a variable changes comment the message appears but does not work

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Uhy.png ,,, look at the red color I want when changing the variables inside the red color does not get anything and when you change only orange color appears message please help me :(

Comment: myRef = myRef.child("comments").child("19").child("comment");

Comment: I searched two days ago but found no useful solution

Comment: I'm sorry but i cannot understand you.

Comment: I did not find the solution but I used his way not a professional, did you find a solution?

Comment: I have finished my application but the problem is still

Comment: The solution above, didn't worked? Did my answer heleped you in any way?